# BeautifulSoup - finding a tag with a certain attribute value doesn't work well

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributes

I am new to python crawling. I played with `find(tag, attribute = 'value')` and found some interesting results.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<a class="cluster_text_headline nclicks(cls_pol.clsart)" href="https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=421&amp;aid=0004679941">text1</a>
<a class="cluster_text_headline nclicks(cls_pol.clsart)" href="https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=032&amp;aid=0003013328">text2</a>
<a class="cluster_text_headline nclicks(cls_pol.clsart)" href="https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=052&amp;aid=0001449034">text3</a>
<a class="cluster_text_headline nclicks(cls_pol.clsart)" href="https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=055&amp;aid=0000819508">text4</a>
<a class="cluster_text_headline nclicks(cls_pol.clsart)" href="https://www.test.com">text5</a>

'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find('a', href="https://www.test.com")
print(a_tags)
```

This returns `<a class="cluster_text_headline nclicks(cls_pol.clsart)" href="https://www.test.com">text5</a>` as expected.

But when I replaced the attribute value in `.find()`, for example, with `'https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=032&amp;aid=0003013328'` (the second link in the code),  `None` is returned. It would be appreciated if anyone can explain why outcomes differ depending on the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is caused by the html parser bs4 uses, and the `&amp;` in your hrefs: when it parses your html source,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

it unescapes `&amp;`, converting `&amp;` into `&`. (see: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5d6aba318ead9cc756ba750a70da41f5def3f8f/Lib/html/parser.py#L326).

it apparently does *not* do the same conversion with the href value you pass to `find`

```
a_tags = soup.find('a', href='https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=032&amp;aid=0003013328')
```

so it ends up trying to match your (escaped) href value
`https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=032&amp;aid=0003013328`

against the *unescaped* href attribute in your source 
`<a href="https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&mid=shm&sid1=100&oid=032&aid=0003013328">text2</a>`

...and fails. this on the other hand, returns the "expected" result:

```
html = '''
<a href="https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&amp;mid=shm&amp;sid1=100&amp;oid=032&amp;aid=0003013328">text2</a>
<a class="cluster_text_headline nclicks(cls_pol.clsart)" href="https://www.test.com">text5</a>
'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    a_tags = soup.find('a', href='https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LSD&mid=shm&sid1=100&oid=032&aid=0003013328')
    print(a_tags)
    a_tags = soup.find('a', href='https://www.test.com')
    print(a_tags)
```